# How to suppress the schtask.exe warning

Tags: cmd

When schtask is invoked on the same Task name the schtask.exe prompts to ask if the task is to be replaced as it already exists:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /TN "Disk Space Checker" /TR "powershell.exe D:\DiskSpaceMonitor\DiskSpaceMonitor.ps1" /SC MINUTE /MO 30
```

How can I suppress this warning and always ask the schtask to replace the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your OS version. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> /F
>
> A value that forcefully creates the task and suppresses warnings if the specified task already exists.
>
> **Windows XP and Windows Server 2003**:  This option is not available.